# Where can I find an older version of the documentation for an official Google Cloud Python library?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-python

I am trying to find the documentation for the 0.39.0 version of the Google Cloud Vision Python library. This would help me to upgrade it to the latest 2.0.0 version, which has backwards incompatible changes.

The latest one can be found here: https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/index.html

I tried playing with Google and the `/latest/` path in the URL to find older versions for the documentation, but failed so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a version picker for every Google Client Library at the right bottom of every documentation

Answer (score 0):

Aparently there was a short glitch - putting the version number instead of `latest` no longer gives me a 404 now.

https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/0.39.0/index.html